# How to connect NodeJS and Java?

Tags: java, node.js, interface

I need for my Node application to be able to send and recieve data to/from an already running Java app or to launch Java app from Node.

So, is there a way to send data from NodeJS to Java and back?

My goal is to have something like this:

```java
// In Java:
J2JSInterface.setReciever(msg -> System.out.println("Message from JS: " + msg));
J2JSInterface.send("Hello from Java!");

// In Java console:
// Message from JS: Hello from JS!
```

```js
// In Node:
JS2JInterface.setReciever(msg => console.log(`Message from Java: ${msg}`))
JS2JInterface.send("Hello from JS!")

// In Node console:
// Message from Java: Hello from Java!
```

P.S.: I Tried using JNI and Node Api in one C++ library together, ([code](https://gist.github.com/Mrcavas/4be02db1b4c0e01bb952b52847bacd45)) but it won't work because Node and Java will load two independent instances of the library and these instances can't interact with each other. (or can they?)

Comment: Why don't you use websocket?

Comment: @AhmetUğur, I think it would be too slow for my needs, but I should definitely try it...

Comment: If you can analyze the data well, websocket should be fine. take it easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really tend to overcomplicate things...

**TCP is the solution** for really fast communicating. When I checked the latency, I was shocked, because it was around 0 to 1 ms. Thanks to [AhmetUğur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677796/ahmet-u%c4%9fur) for pointing out that I could just use websockets!